# displaying a string from a struct using pointers?

Tags: c++

Im using pointers to display data input by the user, but when I try to display the data input by the user, the strings don't display on case 3. Instead blanks do. I changed the strings to chars and it worked. just wondering why chars will display, but strings will not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct employeeRec
{
string employee_id;
string last_name;
string first_name;
float hrs_worked;
float pay_rate;
float tax_rate;
};

int main()
{
bool again = true;
int recorded = 0, remaining = 20;

while (again)
{
    const int max = 20;
    int written, option;
    employeeRec *p, records[max];

    p = &records[0];

    cout << "\n1 - Enter new employee(s)\n"
         << "2 - Find one employee record\n"
         << "3 - Display all employee records\n"
         << "4 - Quit\n\n";

    cout << "Enter an option: ";
    cin >> option;

    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "\nHow many records do you wish to enter? (Max total of 20 records): ";
            cin >> written;

            cin.ignore();

            if (written < 0)
            {
                written = written * -1;
            }

            for (int n = 0; n < written; n++)
            {
                cout << "\nRecord #" << n << "\n";
                cout << "1 of 6 - Enter Employee ID: ";
                getline(cin, p -> employee_id);

                cout << "\n2 of 6 - Enter Employee Last Name: ";
                getline(cin, p -> last_name);

                cout << "\n3 of 6 - Enter Employee First Name: ";
                getline(cin, p -> first_name);

                cout << "\n4 of 6 - Enter Hours Worked: ";
                cin >> p -> hrs_worked;

                cout << "\n5 of 6 - Enter Pay Rate: ";
                cin >> p -> pay_rate;

                cout << "\n5 of 6 - Enter Pay Rate: ";
                cin >>p -> tax_rate;

                cin.ignore();

                cout << "\nEmployee Recorded\n";

                p++;
            }

            recorded = recorded + written;
            remaining = remaining - recorded;

            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
           cout << "\nFind an employee option";
           break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < written; n++)
            {
                cout << "\n\nEmployee ID: " << p -> employee_id << "\n";
                cout << "Last Name: " << p -> last_name << "\tFirst Name: " << p -> first_name << "\n";
                cout << "Hours Worked: " << p -> hrs_worked << "\tPayrate: " << p -> pay_rate << "\tTax Rate: " << p -> tax_rate << "\n\n";
                p++;
            }
            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            cout << "\nQuitting...";
            again = false;
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            cout << "Not a valid option. Enter a valid option.\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe do a `cout.flush()` after the output lines?

Comment: tried that, too, but no effect.

Comment: Move declarations of your variables out of the `while` loop. As written, you don't carry any state from one iteration of the loop to the next. E.g. in option 3, `written` is an uninitialized variable.

Comment: i took records out of the loop, and now the strings display. thank you for the explanation!